# Oracle Hierarchical Query: Include Start With in result and optimization

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Hi I have the following Hierarchical Query. May I know how to include the start with pc.Parent="abc" in the result too?

```
select pc.child
from parentChild pc
start with pc.Parent="abc"
connect by nocycle prior pc.child = pc.parent;
```

I'm using the above query to update all the child + start with parent values.

```
update person set ..... where person.id in (select pc.child
    from parentChild pc
    start with pc.Parent="abc"
    connect by nocycle prior pc.child = pc.parent)
```

May I know if there is a more effective way to update all the children and itself?

I'm considering taking out the list of children and updating them individually using hibernate.

Please share your suggestion :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution without inserting "parent,null child" values is using dual

```
select pc.child
from parentChild pc
start with pc.Parent="abc"
connect by nocycle prior pc.child = pc.parent
union
Select pc.parent from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, use `SELECT pc.parent` instead of `SELECT pc.child`. This way even the parent will be included in the result.

For the second question (update), i don't see any problem with that query. I'm using CONNECT BY PRIOR in the similar manner (to generate lists for IN) and never had any issues with it. Infact, I've never seen any other approach to update a tree hierarchy on Oracle.

In response to comments regarding first question, (SQLDeveloper, 10g):

```
CREATE TABLE mytree( parent_id INT, child_id INT );

INSERT INTO mytree VALUES ( 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO mytree VALUES ( 2, 3 );
INSERT INTO mytree VALUES ( 3, NULL );

SELECT 
lpad(' ', LEVEL)||parent_id
FROM
mytree
START WITH mytree.parent_id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR mytree.child_id = mytree.parent_id ;
1
 2
  3
```

Comment: but child whom are not parent aka no children aka leaf will not be in the list.

Comment: Shouldn't behave like that, tried it ? Perhaps remove the NOCYCLE, as it shouldn't loop anyways ?

Comment: well logically speaking, it shouldn't work because a child might not be a parent.. example a leaf

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I notice the difference... INSERT INTO mytree VALUES ( 3, NULL ); >> adult without children are not inserted in the the table for me.